# How to set a user-selected background colour in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How to take user-selected colour and use it as the background colour of the tkinter frame?

```
list2 = ["red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "yellow"];
droplist = OptionMenu(root, c, *list2)
droplist.config(width=15)
c.set('select your colour')
droplist.place(x=240, y=320)
root.configure(bg=c)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's make this work by filling in some missing pieces:

```
import tkinter as tk

COLORS = ["red", "blue", 'green', 'cyan', 'magenta', "yellow"]

def change_color(*args):
    root.configure(bg=color.get())

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(width=200, height=200)

color = tk.StringVar(root)
color.trace('w', change_color)
color.set(COLORS[0])

om = tk.OptionMenu(root, color, *COLORS)
label = tk.Label(root, text='Select your color')

om.pack(side="top")
label.pack(side="top")

root.mainloop()
```

The primary missing piece was the `StringVar` associated with the `OptionMenu` which allows you to interogate it.  To associate a callback function with the `OptionMenu`, we *trace* changes to the `StringVar`.

Comment: I recommend moving the calls to `.pack()` on a separate line. While it doesn't matter in this little example, it's a bad practice to put them on the same line. Beginners *always* get tripped up by this. It might also be good to explicitly set the `side` option since explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I'm a "turtle atop tkinter" type so my tkinter examples tend to be minimalist.  If I supply `pack()` arguments, they're as likely to be wrong as right!  If you don't mind editing my code, I'd appreciate your input as far as tkinter correctness.

Comment: _" If I supply pack() arguments, they're as likely to be wrong as right!"_ - that is not true. If you don't supply arguments then it will use the defaults. I'm just suggesting you hard-code the defaults so that beginners know exactly what is happening.